# DB2 inserting both timestamp values and null values into a nullable timestamp column

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

When selecting timestamps (which are nullable with defualt null) from a source table through a PHP script and trying to insert into an identical destination table,
I get the error 'SYNTAX of date, time or timestamp value not valid SQL state 22008'. I believe it's because some source records are null. When the script runs, I get about half the records inserted into my destination table successfully but only the ones that have actual timestamp values. The null records haven't been inserted.

My statements:

```
    SELECT
        TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION
    FROM TABLE1;

    INSERT INTO TABLE2 (EXPIRATION_T)
    VALUES ($TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION);
```

The problem is that half of my  source records are null and the other half are TIMESTAMP with a degree of 6

The definition of source and destination tables have the column as 'TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION FOR COLUMN 0011TTT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL' and 'EXPIRATION_T FOR COLUMN 00EETTT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL'

WHat can I do to get the null values to insert as well?

UPDATE: CREATION STATEMENTS

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ( 
    ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( 
    START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 ),

    TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION FOR COLUMN 0011TTT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL )   

    RCDFMT TABLE1      ; 

CREATE TABLE TABLE2 ( 
    ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( 
    START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 ),

    EXPIRATION_T} FOR COLUMN 00EETTT TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL )   

    RCDFMT TABLE2      ;
```

UPDATE: PHP SCRIPT

```
    $getDev = "
    SELECT 
        ID,
        TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION 
    FROM TABLE1
";

$stmt = odbc_exec($DB2connDEV, $getDev);

while($gettingItems = odbc_fetch_array($stmt)){

    $rows[] = $gettingItems;
}

foreach($rows as $row){

    $originalID = $row['ID'];
    $expiration = $row['TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION'];


    $insertTable = "INSERT INTO table2 (id,expiration_t) VALUES (
        $originalID,
        '$expiration')";

    $stmt = odbc_exec($DB2connPROD, $insertTable);
}
```

Comment: Paste the least `CREATE TABLE...` code that we can use to reproduce your problem into your question. Include both TABLE1 and TABLE2. When you try to insert NULL, what's the value of `$TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION`? Is it NULL? (No quotes, no blanks, not an empty string.)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' When I try to insert the null rows, I just get the error but it doesn't insert at all. The rows in question have ```<null>``` as the value in the source table

Comment: but printing those rows in the console it just shows blanks

Comment: Please show PHP script so we can see parameter being passed. Remember empty string is not same as `null` in both PHP and SQL.

Comment: @Parfait just updated with php script as well

Comment: Why not run a insert-select query: `INSERT INTO table2 (id, expiration_t) SELECT ID, TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION FROM TABLE1`? You avoid any loops.

Comment: I'm selecting from a development database on one database server/IP and inserting into another but we don't have any replication setup so this is the best way to handle it for now @Parfait

Comment: @Parfait also, I do see what you;re saying where the DB says it's null but the pHp console print out is just empty. So what would be the best solution there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parameterization with a [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php) and not string interpolation such as this `'$expiration'` that renders `null` to empty string:

```php
$apn_stmt = odbc_prepare($DB2connPROD, "INSERT INTO table2 (id, expiration_t) VALUES (?, ?)");
$sel_stmt = odbc_exec($DB2connDEV, "SELECT ID, TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION FROM TABLE1");

while($gettingItems = odbc_fetch_array($sel_stmt)) { 
    $rows[] = $gettingItems; 
} 

foreach($rows as $row) { 
    $originalID = $row['ID'];
    $expiration = ($row['TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION'] == '' ? NULL : $row['TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION']);
    $insertTable = odbc_execute($apn_stmt, array($originalID, $expiration));
}
```

Comment: ok I did try this and now it seems as though the NULL is giving me this issue "invalid parameter number SQL state S1002

Comment: Possibly fetch returns empty string instead of `null`. Check by echoing `is_null($row['TIMESTAMP_EXPIRATION'])` in loop. And see update checking and assigning with tertiary operator.